# Caching headers in NSURLConnection?

Tags: iphone, caching, nsurlconnection

I am getting a 304 response from an API-call which is fine, because the body did not change. However, a HTTP-header-field in the response has changed! This change is not reflected in NSURLConnection's response object. It's as if the HTTP-headers are loaded from a cached copy of the response locally.

Is there a way to keep 304-caching (based on ETags) while having up to date headers?

[NSURLCachePolicy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURLRequestCachePolicy) doesn't seem to have a value for that..

Comment: Which header in the response is different and not reflected correctly?

Comment: A custom header. In our case it's called "X-User-Must-Update-Profile", so the client knows to direct the user there to check his profile.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think NSURLConnection is going to work for you. I asked the Apple developers in the labs at WWDC '13 about cached responses and custom header values, and they told me to use a lower level connection method (such as [CFNetworking](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/Introduction/Introduction.html)) or a third party library which implemented their own (someone told me [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) handles it well).

Comment: Hmm.. that doesn't sound very promising.

Comment: I think you'll find AFNetworking to be pretty feature rich. I've played around with it on several POCs and was happy with it. A lot more happy than using CFNetworking! I've found the Apple frameworks are very opinionated - for the most part they aren't very flexible.

Comment: Perhaps. But I've written my own wrappers around NSURLConnection in this case and it would require a lot of rewriting at the moment.. But I will certainly try it out the next time I'm starting from scratch.